# Get events from youtube app on different app in android or ios

Tags: android, ios, youtube

Is there a way to get notified on a mobile app when user starts to play or stop a video on youtube app with its info like url of video on android or ios?

Answer (score 0):

you will have your answers on it : https://developers.google.com/youtube ^^

Comment: I know this api but it helps to use it inside your app to control youtube. My purpose is to collect information from outside of my app. I would like to know which videos it is playing on youtube app. There maybe a straightforward way that youtube provides or maybe a workaround like intercepting requests. That is what I am searching for.

Comment: ie recover activity in real time?

Comment: I don't know what did you mean with recover activity but possibly same thing. Just want to get notified when a person plays a video on youtube app and stop with the url of video.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/activities                 I don't find much, but I think it comes close to what you want, right?

Comment: Yes, I also saw that api but it relates to channels rather than individual user activities. Actually, first I would like to implement my system on a browser extension which is quite easy to get that information (with content scripts or tab events). I just changed my idea to implement it on mobile app this is why I asked this question.

Comment: In this case you have to try to see with the google activity API for users and filtered the activities compared to youtube https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/